# NHibernate - LazyLoad - No persister found for

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

When I use LazyLoad in NHibernate for my Entities I get the fallowing Exception:

NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: PrivilegeLevelProxy

PrivilegeLevel is an Entity. It has also mapped correctly (it works without LazyLoad()). I ask me, why should NHibernate needs a Persister for a Proxy-Object?

Comment: Are you using fluent configuration or mapping files? This error sounds like if `PrivilegeLevel` is not mapped.

Comment: I use fluent. PrivilegeLevel is mapped. When I remove the LazyLoad() from the class-mappings, it is working ok.

Comment: is PrivilegeLevel subclass, maybe that is the issue

Comment: What version of NHibernate do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't need persister for proxies. This error probably means that NHibernate didn't get the chance to either lazy load the proxy, or the session has failed to recognize that the PrivilegeLevel is a proxy.

Are you using any custom interceptors? If you do, you need to override `GetEntityName` method.

Here are some similar SO questions that might help:
[No persister for: Castle.Proxies.<EntityName>Proxy and lazy="true" in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434415/no-persister-for-castle-proxies-entitynameproxy-and-lazy-true-in-nhibernate)
[No Persister for: error on save with INotifyPropertyChanged Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403176/no-persister-for-error-on-save-with-inotifypropertychanged-interceptor)